# Celery doesn`t start task python django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, celery, django-celery

My application doesn`t call celery task

my settings.py:

```py
CLICKHOUSE_HOST = '127.0.0.1'
CLICKHOUSE_PORT = '6379'

CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://' + CLICKHOUSE_HOST + ':' + CLICKHOUSE_PORT + '/0'
CELERY_BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {'visibility_timeout': 60}
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = "Australia/Tasmania"
CELERY_TASK_TRACK_STARTED = True
CELERY_TASK_TIME_LIMIT = 30 * 60

CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'django-db'
CELERY_CACHE_BACKEND = 'django-cache'
```

Here is **init**.py in referal_app directory:

```py
from __future__ import absolute_import
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

Here is my view that must call celery task:

```py
class DefineView(View):

    def get(self, request):
        create_points.delay(1, 2)
        return render(request, 'main/homepage.html', {})
```

Here is my task (just test for working):

```py
from celery import shared_task

from referal_app.celery import app


@shared_task
def create_points(a, b):
    with open('e:\\txt.txt', 'w') as file:
        for _ in range(1):
            file.write(f'{a + b}')
    return 1
```

Here is celery settings in referal_app directory:

```py
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'referal_app.settings')

app = Celery('referal_app')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

app.autodiscover_tasks()


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print(f'Request: {self.request!r}')
```

When i launching celery i cant see function lounching
Here is `celery -A referal_app worker -l INFO` command output:

```
[tasks]
  . main.tasks.create_points
  . referal_app.celery.debug_task

[2021-05-28 19:42:52,266: INFO/MainProcess] celery@DESKTOP-LM7RKH1 ready.
[2021-05-28 19:42:52,745: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: referal_app.celery.debug_task[e42e42e2-a3d2-4721-ae37-a35abfe31ca6]
[2021-05-28 19:42:52,747: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: main.tasks.create_points[22d35a11-de3e-4b68-8777-7e4b8756c3bd]
[2021-05-28 19:42:53,870: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: main.tasks.create_points[2211846f-7be7-49c1-9628-d4806fbd4bc0]
[2021-05-28 19:42:53,872: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: referal_app.celery.debug_task[181a599b-5b3b-4e7d-96f7-03f5a7a7d2f0]
[2021-05-28 19:42:54,329: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-11] child process 11056 calling self.run()
[2021-05-28 19:42:54,337: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-12] child process 11676 calling self.run()
[2021-05-28 19:42:54,338: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-9] child process 6560 calling self.run()
[2021-05-28 19:42:54,342: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-10] child process 16992 calling self.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to fire up the celery process

run this command to test the celery (you need to run this command into the Django project directory)

```
celery -A <django_project> worker -l info
```

if everything works fine, then you are ready to serve celery in the production

I suggest using **supervisor**, let's install that
install **supervisor**

```
sudo apt-get install supervisor
```

Now create a config file

```
sudo nano /etc/supervisor/conf.d/<app>.conf
```

here is the example (Here I use miniconda)

```
[program:celery]
command=/home/<user>/miniconda3/envs/venv/bin/celery -A <django_project> worker -l info
directory=<django_project>
user=<user>
group=www-data
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile=/<log_dir>/log/access.log
redirect_stderr=true
numprocs=3
priority=998
```

Finally, use this command to update **supervisor**

```
sudo supervisorctl reread
sudo supervisorctl update
```

Run the following commands to stop, start, and/or check the status of the celery program (here app name celery)

```
sudo supervisorctl stop celery
sudo supervisorctl start celery
sudo supervisorctl status celery
```

Comment: This is not work for me, I add output of this command